# System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.DataAvailable usage error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to achieve this in my C# client code:

```
try
{
    Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
    String str= String.Empty;
    while(stream.DataAvailable)
    {
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        str= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        Debug.Log(str);
    }
}
```

For which I get the error:

> The member 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.DataAvailable' cannot be used as method or delegate

On the example given by MSDN on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx) it is clearly used in the do-while loop. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Dave Zych thanks for the edit.

Comment: What happens if you do stream.DataAvailable == true. I know its technically the same thing but there's no harm in trying it!

Comment: @LexWebb Tried, no good :/

Comment: Are you *sure* that's your exact code? It sounds like you're attempting to call `DataAvailable` as a method, i.e. `while(stream.DataAvailable())`.

Comment: Yes it is the exact code, I tried it with parenthesis before when the error popped, I fixed it and saved it but the error won't go away. @DaveZych

Comment: Try restarting visual studio.

Comment: It must be something to do with the Mono framework Unity uses. The compiler must be causing some weird issues as that should absolutely compile. Have you tried running compiling it in a standard .Net application?

Comment: @LexWebb that was it, the error disappeared. Strange it didn't go on my first attempt to fix it by rebuilding the project. Any idea how do I close this question?

Comment: Was it me you meant to tag? Was it restarting VS or my comment that helped? You can close it by creating an answer with the solution that fixed your issue and then marking it as the answer.

Comment: @LexWebb Yes I meant to tag you. Rebuilding fixed it, though your comment has made a certain image in my mind now that Mono framework can be moody at times. You may post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an issue to do with the Mono compiler, it should be able to compile the statement correctly. Cleaning and re-compiling the project should get the compiler to do what it should be doing!